# Gradient of a function in curvilinear coordinates

Tags: differential-geometry, definition, vector-analysis

Let's take a domain $ D $ in $ \mathbb{R}^2 $, parametrized by the chart $ \phi(t_1,t_2):I_2\to D $, where $ I_2 $ is the unit square without boundary. Assume that a function is defined in this domain $ f(x,y):D\to\mathbb{R} $ with gradient $ \nabla f(x,y)=\left[\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y), \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y)\right] $.
Writing the expression of $ f(x,y) $ in the new coordinates $ (t_1,t_2) $, that is $ f(x(t_1,t_2),y(t_1,t_2),z(t_1,t_2)) $, I obtain a new expression of the kind $ f(t_1,t_2) $. Now I want to know the gradient of $ f $ in the new coordinates. By definition (according to Zorich, Mathematical Analysis II) the gradient vector is the vector associated with the differential form $ \mathrm{d}\phi^*f(t_1,t_2)(\tau) $, where $\tau$ is the generic vector in the tangent space at $(t_1,t_2)$.

I have understood that, in general, to a differential 1-form:

$$\omega(t_1,t_2)(\tau) = a_1(t_1,t_2) \mathrm{d}t_1(\tau) + a_2(t_1,t_2) \mathrm{d}t_2(\tau)  $$

I can always associate the vector:

$$ \mathbf{V}_\omega(t_1,t_2)=\omega(t_1,t_2)\left(\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0  \end{bmatrix}\right)  \mathbf{e}_1(t_1,t_2) + \omega(t_1,t_2)\left(\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1  \end{bmatrix}\right)  \mathbf{e}_2(t_1,t_2) =\frac{a_1(t_1,t_2)}{\sqrt{E_1(t_1,t_2)}} \mathbf{e}_1(t_1,t_2) + \frac{a_2(t_1,t_2)}{\sqrt{E_2(t_1,t_2)}}\mathbf{e}_2(t_1,t_2)$$

where $ \mathbf{e}_1(t_1,t_2) $, $ \mathbf{e}_2(t_1,t_2) $, $ \sqrt{E_1(t_1,t_2)} $ and $ \sqrt{E_2(t_1,t_2)} $ are:

$$ \mathbf{e}_1(t_1,t_2)=\begin{bmatrix} 1/\left |\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial \phi_1}{\partial t_1}\\ 
\frac{\partial \phi_2}{\partial t_1}
\end{pmatrix}  \right | \\ 0  \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 1/\sqrt{E_1(t_1,t_2)} \\ 0  \end{bmatrix} $$

$$ \mathbf{e}_2(t_1,t_2)=\begin{bmatrix} 0\\ 1/\left |\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial \phi_1}{\partial t_2}\\ 
\frac{\partial \phi_2}{\partial t_2}
\end{pmatrix}  \right |  \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1/\sqrt{E_2(t_1,t_2)}  \end{bmatrix} $$

that is, they are precisely those vectors that generate, through the Jacobian matrix of the chart $\phi$, ortonormal vectors in the tangent space at the point $(x,y)=\phi(t_1,t_2) $.

With this in mind I understand immediately that the gradient of $f(t_1,t_2)$ must have this form:

$$ \mathrm{grad}f(t_1,t_2)=\frac{\frac{\partial f}{\partial t_1}(t_1,t_2)}{\sqrt{E_1(t_1,t_2)}} \mathbf{e}_1(t_1,t_2) + \frac{\frac{\partial f}{\partial t_2}(t_1,t_2)}{\sqrt{E_2(t_1,t_2)}}\mathbf{e}_2(t_1,t_2). $$

Having said that, I have a question only on an intuitive level.
I've always imagined the gradient as that vector to be multiplied (inner product) by a "displacement" vector, obtaining as a result a number that tells me (first order) how much the value of the function would change if I made just that "displacement". **Why, in curvilinear coordinates, this "displacement" has not to be referred to the canonical unit vectors of $I_2$, but to the vectors $ \mathbf{e}_1(t_1,t_2) $, $ \mathbf{e}_2(t_1,t_2) $ (which are not fixed, but scale point by point)?**
If, for example, I think in terms of polar coordinates ($t_1=r, t_2=\theta $), am I basically saying that I shouldn't think of a "displacement" in $\theta $ measured in radians, but should I think it in radians/meter? If this is indeed the case, this thing appears to me (but it is surely because I am still too ignorant) as a complication rather than a simplification.

Comment: Dot product of gradient with a unit displacement yields instantaneous rate of change w.r.t. displacement in that direction. $\theta$ is not a displacement, it is a coordinate variable

Comment: "displacement in $\theta$" = $\Delta\theta$.
My question is about the fact that $\Delta\theta \neq \Delta\theta / r$.

Comment: In other word, what is the advantage to express the gradient as $ \mathrm{grad}f(t_1,t_2)=\frac{\frac{\partial f}{\partial t_1}(t_1,t_2)}{\sqrt{E_1(t_1,t_2)}} \mathbf{e}_1(t_1,t_2) + \frac{\frac{\partial f}{\partial t_2}(t_1,t_2)}{\sqrt{E_2(t_1,t_2)}}\mathbf{e}_2(t_1,t_2) $ instead of $ \mathrm{grad}f(t_1,t_2)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial t_1}(t_1,t_2)\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0  \end{bmatrix} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial t_2}(t_1,t_2)\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} $ ?

Comment: Like I pointed out, you want to differentiate w.r.t. ACTUAL displacement, not w.r.t. a variable. $\theta$ is not an actual displacement

Comment: What do you mean with “actual”? Could you show me the displacement vector you are thinking about, please?

Comment: The easiest check is to see the unit of your gradient. In SI, unit for displacement is meter so the gradient should have a unit of ... / m. $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta}$ on the other hand, has a unit of .../rad.